# ASUS Laptop E203MA won't turn on

Tags: asus-laptop

I have ASUS Laptop E203MA.

Today, my bag fell down, with my laptop inside. After that, it worked well, but later, it suddenly turned off, and I cannot turn it on. The Power indicator blinks. (It connected to the charger)

Please help?

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally I solved that.
I just pressed the power button until the power indicator stopped blinking, and I pressed again - and it turned on!